# Why doesn't the SB 800 fit securily on a Nikon d610 mount shoe?

Tags: nikon, flash, compatibility, hotshoe

SB800 speed light doesn't fit securely on my Nikon d610 mount shoe.  Is there an adapter available or do I need to purchase a new flash?

Comment: Sounds as if either your camera or the flash is broken. Just to rule out the obvious: You have locked the flash in position after sliding it into the flash mount on the camera? On the SB800, just above the flash shoe, there is a lever. You have to turn it to the left to mount and unmount the flash, and to the right (in the position where it says 'LOCK') to lock it to the camera.

Comment: Do you mean securely or tightly?  There can be a slight wiggle, but it should not come off if locked.

Comment: We've had a similar question before with regard to a slight change in the Nikon hot shoe fit. For some reason I can't find it now.

Comment: Possibly related https://petapixel.com/2015/05/05/nikon-d750-hot-shoe-reportedly-causing-problems-by-being-slightly-too-long/ — but that's for the D750?

Comment: @mattdm, maybe https://fstoppers.com/originals/stop-fighting-hot-shoe-your-nikon-d750-110295 instead? More pics :), and an actual solution to the gap issue.

Comment: This question is either trivially answered (the manufacturer of the flash did not make the connector the right size to attach securely to the camera) or impossible to answer because of insufficient information. OP is unlikely to return because appears anonymous.

Answer (score 1):

As [WayneF comments](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97003/75526#comment177804_97003), some wiggle can be expected, and the flash should be considered secure as long as contacts are well connected (the flash does not misfire) and the flash does not come detached during normal use.

If the flash has never fit securely, it may be a manufacturing issue in which the connector was not sized to fit the camera well. (I consider any change on the camera side of the mount, as [Michael Clark comments](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97003/why-doesnt-the-sb-800-fit-securily-on-a-nikon-d610-mount-shoe/101302#comment177811_97003), to be included in this category.)

If it had previously fit properly, then the flash or the camera may have been damaged. More information would be needed to determine what happened.

There are various flash accessories you can use as a work around for the issue, such as voltage regulators, remote triggers, or extension cables. However, using any device that extends the length of the flash will add leverage that could result in damage to the camera or flash unit if the flash is bumped.

If you like DIY projects, you may be able to make a shim or reshape the flash connector with epoxy.